# Angular no caching of localhost api urls when calling from webserver

Tags: angular

Goal: Caching specific urls from http://localhost/api

Actual result: No caching at all.

Expected result: Caching the responses with the images as blobs of the urls.

Detailed description: Angular App is running on webserver with https certificate. The API is started local and is running under the address http://localhost:80/api. Every call is working fine and is responsing.

The caching works fine if I run both the angular app and the API on localhost. So I think its a cross origin problem or that the service worker is ignoring the localhost urls.

ngsw.json

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ],
        "urls": [
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/**",
          "http://localhost/api/article/**",
          "http://localhost/api/detail/**",
          "http://localhost/api/item/preview?id=**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api-performance",
      "urls": [
        "article/**",
        "detail/**",
        "item/preview?id=*"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "performance",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "3d"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The urls i want to cache are pretty dynamic after the last front slash:

```
"http://localhost/api/article/${articleId}",
"http://localhost/api/detail/${detailId}",
"http://localhost/api/item/preview?id=${previewId}"
```

All responses are bytestreams (blobs) which I am converting to SafeUrls.

Already tried:

- changed http to https
- inserted the urls into `urls` property of `assetGroups`
- removed the wildcards
- added front slashes
- removed front slashes
- changing urls to relative ones
- changing urls to absolute ones

Cant provide a minimum example of the webserver and api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some testing: The problem is caused by the localhost-address. I tried several APIs from the "internet" with a real ip address/url with wildcard and without.

In addition it is probably a security issue to allow and use a self local hosted API.